# Showing that a GARCH(1, 1) model is an ARMA(1, 1) process for squared errors

Tags: time-series, garch

Consider a GARCH(1, 1) model: $$ \sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \epsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta \sigma_{t-1}^2 $$

Where $ \sigma_t $ is the conditional variance at time $ t $, $ \epsilon_{t}^2 $ is the error term in time $t$. In "In Introductory Econometrics for Finance" by Brooks (pg. 418/674), section 8.8, it is shown that this can be represented as an ARMA(1, 1) model for the squared errors. That is, the above can be written as:

$$ \epsilon_t^2 = \alpha_0 + ( \alpha_1 + \beta) \epsilon_{t-1}^2 - \beta w_{t-1} + w_t $$

To do so, the author starts with the statement:

$$ w_t = \epsilon_t^2 - \sigma_t^2 $$

What does this statement mean and how is it valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation is as follows: You start with the conditional variance equation:
\begin{equation}
\sigma_t^2=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2
\end{equation}
Now, add $w_t=\epsilon_t^2-\sigma_t^2$ on both sides. You obtain:
\begin{align}
\sigma_t^2+w_t&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2+w_t \\
\sigma_t^2+\epsilon_t^2-\sigma_t^2&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2+w_t\\
\epsilon_t^2&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2+ w_t \\
\end{align}
Notice that $w_{t-1}=\epsilon_{t-1}^2-\sigma_{t-1}^2$ and therefore $\sigma_{t-1}^2=\epsilon_{t-1}^2-w_{t-1}$. You obtain:
\begin{align}
\epsilon_t^2&=\alpha_0+\alpha_1\epsilon_{t-1}^2+\beta_1(\epsilon_{t-1}^2-w_{t-1})+ w_t \\
 \epsilon_t^2&=\alpha_0+(\alpha_1+\beta_1)\epsilon_{t-1}^2 -\beta_1w_{t-1} +w_t
\end{align}
This is an ARMA(1,1) for the squared shocks if $w_t$ is a white noise process. Check that $E(w_t)=0$ and $Cov(w_t,w_{t+h})=0 , h\geq 1$. If $E(\epsilon_t^4)<\infty$ than $V(w_t)<\infty$ and $w_t$ is a weak white noise process. One thing that gets obvious when looking at this equation is that the $\epsilon_t$ are uncorrelated but not independent because the squared shocks follow an ARMA(1,1) process. Furthermore, it is now easy to derive the ACF of $\epsilon_t^2$. You can see that the ACF is always positive and converges at rate $\alpha_1+\beta_1$ to zero.

Comment: Thanks - so $ w_t = \epsilon^2_t - \sigma_t^2 $ here in your derivation is just notation?

Comment: Yes, this differs from book to book.

Comment: @Lars: I always wondered how that was the case so thanks.

Comment: @Lars . I went over your answer carefully and it was clear. Thank you. But I had one question. You say that the $\epsilon_t$ are uncorrelated. I tried to prove this but was not successful. Then I thought about it and that doesn't make sense to me because $\epsilon_t$ is a function of $u_t^2$ ( and $\sigma^2_t$ which is not observed ) which is a function of $\epsilon_{t-1}$. So it seems to me that the $\epsilon_t$ have to be correlated atleast at lag one. Thanks for any clarification of that statement.

Comment: To proof that $\epsilon_t$ is uncorrelated, note that ($h \geq 1$): $Cov(\epsilon_t,\epsilon_{t-h})=E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-h})=E(E(\epsilon_t\epsilon_{t-h} \vert \mathcal F_{t-1}))=E(\epsilon_{t-h}E(\epsilon_t \vert \mathcal F_{t-1}))=0$ as $E(\epsilon_{t} \vert \mathcal F_{t-1})=E(\sigma_{t}u_{t} \vert \mathcal F_{t-1})=\sigma_{t}E(u_{t} \vert \mathcal F_{t-1})=0$.

Comment: Thanks Lars but does $\epsilon_t$  equal $\sigma_t u_t$ or does it equal $\sqrt{(w_t + \sigma^2)}$. OP defined error term as the square ?

Comment: Lars, just a heads up that your definition of $\epsilon_t$ in your proof  immediately above seems to be related to its definition in the ARCH framework. But how you defined it in this question in order to show its equivalence to GARCH is different. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the notations used in the question. Now, $\epsilon_t=\sigma_t u_t$ and $w_t=\epsilon_t^2-\sigma_t^2=\sigma_t^2(u_t^2-1)$. If you wanted to show that $w_t$ is uncorrelated, obverse that for $h \geq 0$, $Cov(w_t,w_{t-j})=E(w_tw_{t-h})=E(E(w_tw_{t-h}\vert \mathcal F_{t-1}))=E(w_{t-h}E(w_t \vert \mathcal F_{t-1}))=0$

Comment: Hi Lars:  in your original answer, you said that the $\epsilon_t$ were uncorrelated. I will assume that that statement is not correct unless given reason to think otherwise. I was trying to show that the $\epsilon_t$ were uncorrelated since that was what you said in your answer. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @WorldGov: The comment section could be confusing  for you since your notation is no longer there. So just a heads up that, based on your original notation,  the $\epsilon_t$  are correlated. It is the $w_t$ that are uncorrelated.

Comment: This is not correct, both  $\epsilon_t$ and $w_t$ are uncorrelated as shown in the comment above.